# How do I write an extension method for a generic type with constraints on type parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, generics

I'm working with a task specific .NET plattform, which is precompiled and not OpenSource.
For some tasks I need to extend this class, but not by inheriting from it. I simply want to add a method.

At first I want to show you a dummycode existing class:

```
public class Matrix<T> where T : new() {
    ...
    public T values[,];
    ...
}
```

I want to extend this class in the following way:

```
public static class MatrixExtension {
    public static T getCalcResult<T>(this Matrix<T> mat) {
        T result = 0;
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

I've got this syntax from many google links so no idea whether it is correct. The compiler tells me no error, but in the end it doesn't work. In the end I want to call this function in the following way:

```
Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>();
...
int aNumber = m.getCalcResult();
```

So anyone got an idea? Thank you for your help!

Regards Nem

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: This is the proper way to use an extension method, but instead of `T result = 0` you should have `T result = default(T)` because T is not initially constrained to `int`.  Other than that, you should check to make sure you have the using statement to include your MatrixExtension class.  You can always check by calling `MatrixExtension.getCalcResult(m)` directly to see if it is working.

Comment: At least the IDE forces me to call the method like this:

    m.getCalcResult<int>();

But when I try to compile this I get an other error:

> 'Matrix<int>' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Matrix<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

By the way this way to call the method makes no sense because the generic Parameter T is already assigned.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying the compiler tells you no error. There are a couple of (compile) errors that I see right away. Not sure what you mean by "error".

Comment: Is there a `GetValue()` method defined for `Matrix<T>`?

Comment: So how would you solve this problem?

Comment: No GetValue() is not already defined.

Comment: You need to define it in the class or as an extension method. Why would you call that method if it doesn't exist?

Comment: sorry GetValue and getCalcResult are the same methods in this example. My fault by copy&paste. But the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Do you get a *compile time* error? Or is getCalcResult not returning the correct value at *run time*?

Comment: I get a compile time error. But at the moment I am looking at answer 2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the same type parameter constraints on the extension method.

This is my attempt at the closest reconstruction of your example that compiles and runs, without any error:

```
public class Matrix<T>  where T : new() {
     public T[,] values;
 }


 public static class MatrixExtension {
     public static T getCalcResult<T>(this Matrix<T> mat)  where T : new() {
         T result = new T();
         return result;
     }
 }

 class Program {
     static void Main(string[] args)  {
        Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>();
        int aNumber = m.getCalcResult();
        Console.WriteLine(aNumber); //outputs "0"
 }
```

Comment: I had been contemplating posting my code, but its exactly the same.

Comment: You can copy/paste _my_ code into a new project to see what happens.

Comment: Yep it works! But now I know what I've not looked at!
`class Matrix<T> where T : new()`
I've totally not looked on that. :(

Comment: At this moment i'm totally confused about how the syntax for this case should look like.

Comment: I've updated your question and my answer based on the new bit.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about `T` for method `GetCalcResult<T>(this Matrix<T> mat) where T : new()`... it returns value of type T which should be *Reference type*... **Question:** shouldn't there be an error on this line `int aNumber = m.getCalcResult();`?

Comment: @Prokurors The `where T : new()` constraint means that it needs a default constructor (so that it may be instantiated). To specify only reference types the constraint to use is `where T : class`.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, the only "error" I'd see is this:

```
T result = 0;
```

You could change that to:

```
T result = default(T);
```

In the case of value types, this will be zero, so it would be safe.

However, you're going to find that this is difficult when you get to the "..." section you've listed.  The basic types (`int`, `double`, etc) don't implement a method you can use to compute your math.  This is a [long time, very highly voted request on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94264/arithmetic-types-like-int-double-decimal-should-implement-iarithmetic-t?wa=wsignin1.0), btw.

While there are workarounds, they make life very difficult.  Unlike templates in C++, C#'s generics really don't support type safe mathematical operations on arbitrary types.

Comment: I think this is my problem which will remain. But that was not my question. My question is how to extend this generic class. For an ungeneric class it is no problem.

Comment: @nemcija: Yes - but extending the generic class is exactly as you did - that's not a problem.  This is what you're going to run into when you get the compiler error fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into "Decorators"...

[Sample showing Decorator patterns](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/PatternsIntro_Decorator.aspx)

A decorator allows you to create a class with its own properties and methods without doing a direct derivation from one specific class.  Then, you can "apply" it to virtually ANY other object.  Then you can apply use your extra methods, or properties you are trying to work with.

This sample was a simple quick find showing such an example attaching itself to "cars" by building "options"...

Comment: That's not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @Jim Schubert, yeah... I know... while I was trying to look up some samples, the mouse touch pad must have been hit... until I got back to adjust...

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I wanted to say... those touchpad submits get me every time. Also, +1 because a decorator could solve the problem and is a viable answer.  My first comment was really directed at how a single-sentence question is better suited for a comment than an answer :\

Comment: @Jim Schubert, yeah... sometimes overly sensitive... and I hate using a mouse unless I'm using a docking station.