# Load from XML/JSON as extension method of object rather than string

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net, extension-methods

I have the code below which takes file containing XML and JSON and deserializes the JSON/XML into objects

```
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("output.json"))
    {
        var rawJsonToLoad = streamReader.ReadLine();
        var jsonWalkOrder = rawJsonToLoad.FromJson<MeterWalkOrder>();
        Debug.WriteLine(jsonWalkOrder.Dump());
    }


    var xml = File.ReadAllText("WalkOrder.xml");
    var xmlTest = xml.LoadFromXML<MeterWalkOrder>();
```

JSON

```
{
    Name: Red Route,
    Meters: 
    [
        {
            __type: "WindowsFormsApplication1.Classes.Meter, WindowsFormsApplication1",
            MeterID: 1,
            SerialNumber: 12345
        },
        {
            __type: "WindowsFormsApplication1.Classes.Meter, WindowsFormsApplication1",
            MeterID: 2,
            SerialNumber: SE
        }
    ]
}
[
    1,
    441,
    2
]
```

XML

```
 <MeterWalkOrder>
      <Name>Red Route</Name>
      <Meters>
        <Meter>
          <MeterID>1</MeterID>
          <SerialNumber>12345</SerialNumber>
        </Meter>
        <Meter>
          <MeterID>2</MeterID>
          <SerialNumber>SE</SerialNumber>
        </Meter>
      </Meters>
    </MeterWalkOrder>
```

Whilst on the surface this does work fine, there is a major drawback with it, it is using extension methods that are all extending the string data type

What I really want to be able to do is to say something like

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("WalkOrder.xml");
var xmlTest = new MeterWalkOrder();
xmlTest.LoadFromXML(xml);
```

How can this be done with an extension method that extends an object rather than string?

I dont like the current approach because there is not enough flexibility in it, it forces the creation of new objects.  For example, using the current method if I had a list of 5 meters and I wanted to add another 10 meters from a string of JSON I wouldnt be able to, because the fromJson would force me to recreate my meters list so I would only have the 10 meters in the file, not those 10 + the 5 that were already in the list

Paul

Edit - Following comments I have tried an extension method which actually demonstrates my issue perfectly

```
  public static class ObjectExtensions
  {
        public static T PopulateFromJson<T>(this T obj)
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("output.json"))
            {  
                var rawJsonToLoad = streamReader.ReadLine();
                obj = rawJsonToLoad.FromJson<T>();
            }

            return obj;
       }
  }
```

If I use the code below...

```
var testJson = new MeterWalkOrder();
testJson.Meters.Add(new Meter() { SerialNumber = "Meter 1" });
testJson.Meters.Add(new Meter() { SerialNumber = "Meter 2" });
testJson.PopulateFromJson();
```

...

After PopulateFromJson I want the object to be preserved - but because fromJson returns a new object it isnt - so my object would only contain the 2 meters from the JSON file, I actually want them added to the end of the list - in short I want to use the existing object not to have a new one created

Paul

Comment: What issues did you run into when trying to create an extension method on `object`?

Comment: Write an extension method for the MeterWalkOrder.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I havent tried as I am not very confident with the syntax of extension methods, especially when they are combined with generics.  I will take a look at the link.  I want the extension method to be available to any class

Comment: The generic extension looks like this: public static T Foo<T>(this T bar)  This method would return an object of the specified type.

Comment: Another example of a generic static method: public static void Foo<T>(this T bar)

Comment: also you will probably need to put a constraint template type so that it will be usable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825952/c-sharp-generic-extension-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928810/how-do-i-write-an-extension-method-for-a-generic-type-with-constraints-on-type-p

Comment: Still cant get my head round this or get it to work I have added my attempt to the main question above